# UITableView crash when selecting

Tags: iphone, uitableview, crash, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a simple table view controller driven by the fetchedResultsController and it crashes very often when I select it and the crash log is like this;

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xc21eb7ad
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3c0ce5d0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                           0x3623c564 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 404
2   UIKit                           0x3622138c -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1312
3   UIKit                           0x36238822 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 202
4   UIKit                           0x361f48c2 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 254
5   QuartzCore                      0x35fa050e -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 210
6   QuartzCore                      0x35fa00b0 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 456
7   QuartzCore                      0x35fa0fd4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 12
8   QuartzCore                      0x35fa09be CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 234
9   QuartzCore                      0x35fa07d0 CA::Transaction::commit() + 312
10  QuartzCore                      0x35fa0634 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 56
11  CoreFoundation                  0x343b793e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 18
12  CoreFoundation                  0x343b5c34 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 272
13  CoreFoundation                  0x343b5f8e __CFRunLoopRun + 742
14  CoreFoundation                  0x34329238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
15  CoreFoundation                  0x343290c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
16  GraphicsServices                0x37f07336 GSEventRunModal + 70
17  UIKit                           0x362452b4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
18  Introdex                        0x0011e538 0xa3000 + 505144
19  Introdex                        0x000a5a24 0xa3000 + 10788

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c5b75d0 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c4f2d22 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 806
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3c4ee374 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 32

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c5b6e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c5b6fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x343b72b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x343b602c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34329238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x343290c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   WebCore                         0x3a328390 RunWebThread(void*) + 440
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5200de _pthread_start + 306
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c51ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c5b6e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c5b6fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x343b72b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x343b602c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34329238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x343290c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x34c4d5be -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Foundation                      0x34cf0c40 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
8   Introdex                        0x0021924c 0xa3000 + 1532492
9   Foundation                      0x34cfa22c __NSThread__main__ + 968
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5200de _pthread_start + 306
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c51ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c5b6e30 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c5b6fd0 mach_msg + 48
2   CoreFoundation                  0x343b72b6 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 126
3   CoreFoundation                  0x343b602c __CFRunLoopRun + 900
4   CoreFoundation                  0x34329238 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352
5   CoreFoundation                  0x343290c4 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
6   Foundation                      0x34c76888 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 304
7   Foundation                      0x34cfa22c __NSThread__main__ + 968
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5200de _pthread_start + 306
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c51ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c5c7594 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x343bb474 __CFSocketManager + 676
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5200de _pthread_start + 306
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c51ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c5c708c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c518afc _pthread_cond_wait + 644
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c518870 pthread_cond_timedwait + 40
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x382fddf6 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 102
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x38410532 JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 78
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x38423030 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5200de _pthread_start + 306
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c51ffa4 thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3c5c708c __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c518afc _pthread_cond_wait + 644
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c522cf8 pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x383a36dc JSC::SlotVisitor::drainFromShared(JSC::SlotVisitor::SharedDrainMode) + 140
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x383a3620 JSC::MarkStackThreadSharedData::markingThreadMain() + 140
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x38423030 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3c5200de _pthread_start + 306
7   libsystem_c.dylib
```

Can somebody please explain me what this crash log means. I could not read it properly and do not know what this actually means. It would be really great if anyone could help me.

Comment: code would help to work out whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at your code, its hard to know where you going wrong.

But still as I know If you are able show the data on Table successfully and getting crash while click on particular row.
Below are some possibilities.

1). make sure you have declared UITableViewDelegate in your controller's header file.

Solution : make sure you have this (in .h file)

```
@interface FavViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

2). forgot to hook-up delegate with File owner

Solution : Open Layout's XIB file --> select UITableView --> in Connection Inspector --> drag delegate to the File's Owner (as per the below image)

[image]

you can achieve same by doing it programmatically in your .m file's viewDidLoad method

```
favourite_tbl.delegate=self;//favourite_tbl is instance of myTableView
```

3). your **didSelectRowAtIndexPath** method (for click on row) should be like

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    selectedIndex = indexPath.row;

    NSLog(@"you have selected %d",selectedIndex);

}
```

Feel free to drop me a comment if you have any trouble in this.